# How do i convert a custom object to the bytes data type and back again?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, casting, byte

I am trying to follow the websocket tutorial that can be found here in the readme of this python github repo:

> https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets

For my use case, I want the client to not pass a string to the websocket server but rather an object. When I tried replacing the generic "Hello World!" parameter that the client sends to the server though I get the following error:

```
TypeError: data must be bytes or str
```

Ok, makes sense. Obviously websocket requires a string or a bytes object to be passed from client to server. My question is how do i easily convert a generic object of some custom class I've created to the bytes/string type using the best practice problem. Obviously, I would also like to be able to convert the object back from the bytes class to the original class type I have declared.

When searching I couldn't find anything talking about how to do this (only how to do this for strings) and tried hard casting by passing my object into the bytes() method but this threw an error.

Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

I am an idiot. Converting the object to JSON works.